# SSH Port forward with secret file(mac)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, port, tableau-api

I have a unique issue where I need Tableau to connect to a Postgres Server under a Bastion Host in AWS. I usually try to

`ssh -i key.pem  ec2-user@bastion_host`

But I wish to know how I can port forward ssh to 5430 so I can do ssh -R 5430:localhost:5430 bastion host but connect . I am kind of confused about the whole setup of how I can ssh with the secret file and still port forward to my localhost so i can connect tableau to localhost:5430. Would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command to reset the port to one other than the default of 80/443.

`tsm topology set-ports --node-name node --port-name gateway:primary --port-value nn`

Article with more detail found [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/server_process_gateway.htm)

Comment: Where is the relevance to the question?

Comment: If you want tableau server to use a different port like 5430, this is the command to do so. It appears this is what the OP is looking for when I read the `so i can connect tableau to localhost:5430` portion of the question.

Comment: Okay, to be fair, that could be also the question. I understand it the way, that the OP is looking only for forwarding the ssh port (already at 5430)

Comment: thanks for clarifying @jeb. I do have to admit, I was only looking at it from that part of the question without much knowledge of ssh.